# How to use visibilitychange instead of beforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need my webapp to send an insert statement when the browser or tab is closed.

I am currently using the code below:

```
function onExit() {

    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('postmessage', 'CALL myinsertstatement()');

    navigator.sendBeacon('insert.php', fd);

}

function sleep(delay) {

    var start = new Date().getTime();

    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);

}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {

    onExit();

    sleep(1000);

});
```

I use the `sleep()` method to delay the window from closing in order to give it enough time to execute the `sendBeacon()` method because without it , it wasn't working most of the time.

With the `sleep()` method, it works all the time with me, but I am worried that it might not work with someone that has slower internet, not to mention that `sendBeacon()` is not supposed to be used with `beforeunload`, it's supposed to be used with `visibilitychange` but I can't figure out how to use `visibilitychange` to accomplish this...

Thank you so much for any guidance!

Comment: According to the MDN documentation, navigator.sendBeacon() is async. So why do you need to manually handle this ? As far as I understand from the doc, the browser should do the trick for you. And for the Page Visibility API , read this article https://www.igvita.com/2015/11/20/dont-lose-user-and-app-state-use-page-visibility/

Comment: @paroxit I already read that article. I didn't find my solution there.

Comment: @paroxit and async is part of the problem. The function runs asynchronously to closing the browser and if it is not completed before closing the browser, the browser does not wait.

Comment: There are some other approaches that I can think of right now. One is to use service workers (but I would not recommend it, since that's not service workers are intented for).  You could use **unload** event with synchronous call but it will slow down the navigation (bad user ex.)  Applying visibility api seems like your only reliable solution

Comment: @paroxit I believe so too, however, i'm not sure how to accomplish this using visibilitychange since visbilitychange fires anytime the browser is hidden, not closed.